# Exchange 2013 - Email Forwarding works for local sender but not external sender

Tags: exchange-2013

I setup email forwarding on a users email to forward their emails to a user inside my organization, but when a external sender sends an email to the forwarded mailbox it does not forward the email. It only forwards emails from users inside my organization? What is going on here? I looked everywhere online and could not find a solution to this.

Microsoft technet does offer any answers
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms.exch.eac.DeliveryOptions(EXCHG.150).aspx?v=15.0.1263.0&l=0

I also tested it with the "Deliver message to both forwardin address and mailbox" box unchecked and checked.

Comment: Any duplicate or conflict transport rule on those inbound message?
I recommend to check message tracking log, then monitor it. For example: Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender "xxx" -MessageSubject "xxxxx" -ResultSize Unlimited | ? {($_.EventID -eq "AgentInfo")}| ? {$_.EventData -like "*ruleID*"} | FL sender,Recipients,MessageSubject,EventData

Comment: I'll try this out, I checked the transport rules but dont see anything.

Comment: Well, run "Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender "xxx" -MessageSubject "xxxxx" -ResultSize Unlimited | FL" to check its delivery process.